# Any suggestion on how to investigate css issue in bootstrap-designed page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Any suggestion on how to check why I get this black box instead of standard bootstrap dropdown? I know, may sound like stupid question, but bear this me...

I checked, there are no referenced css files that could break this functionality. The problem is that I can't right-click on that black box and select "Inspect" to see generated code, the black box disappears once I click on it (right or left). Similarly I cant use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect that element, it disappears.

Generated HTML code:

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="vm.executeAction('ReAssignWorkOrder')" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Service Provider</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-model="vm.data.ServiceProvider" disabled="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Re-Assign To</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="Someone1">Someone1</option>
            <option value="Someone2">Someone2</option>
            <option value="Someone3">Someone3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Progress Note</label>
        <textarea class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" rows="4" ng-model="vm.woReAssign.ProgressNote"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Re-Assign</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Re-Assign and Dispatch</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Same thing happens with html input date field:

Comment: any example/live link?

Comment: here, posted generated code fragment, no live link, internal project

Comment: M not able to see any black box . Try with hard refresh it might be browser problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks for a hint, it is a browser bug, Chrome v 53 - bad, 54 - good.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Whoever voted to close the question - I dont understand the reason, dont you want other people to know it was **Chrome bug** ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using chrome responsive view. some time chrome responsive view caused this king of problems . just exit the responsive view and resize chrome window. and you will not get this black box. there is not issue on your code.